# single MX record for all subdomains (gsuite)

Tags: dns, subdomain, sendgrid, google-workspace, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to route all my inbound mails for subdomains to sendgrid mail service.
I have added an MX record entry using wildcard (*)

[image]

When I try to send a mail to one of my subdomain ex:-(user@subdomain.mydomain.com) gmail was showing me an error **the domain could not be found**

[image]

Any help would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

MX records to not have Wildcards, A records do... MX records have Priority and are for the Domain you set. To service Subdomain emails (which is odd), you would need to configure that outside of DNS and within the app that expects the emails to come-in (Sendgrid)

You should setup specific MX record for each subdomain, not use wildcard

Once you have a valid email, that your MX server is able to recognize a a valid mailbox, then you will be able to send to that email.

Comment: Hi Ron, looks like the wildcard entry is working fine. It just took some time to update the DNS records. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: As long as Sendgrid (in your case) is happy with the setup you did, you are good.